# how to create static lib and include in other xcode projects as well??

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to make static lib but  no success. 
I followed  him  http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html
but of no use.
According to him drag class file in static lib and then delete so what's the point of dragging??

After my lib is generated I am getting error

```
ld: library not found for -ltestlib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/xcode3.2/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Please help me from scratch as how to generate and use static library using xcode.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you make ".a" library file? If yes, drag your library and associated header files into your actual application project. Compile and Build. You don't have to delete.

Comment: i have .a file but thats in red color ( should i put my all .m classes in .a??)

Comment: in .a there are 2 icon  copy header and copy source  should i put all .h and .m to these and then build??

Comment: why ld: library not found for -lStaticLib???  i have the file still its say no what to do now??